# Spring Boot - require api key AND x509, but not for all endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, x509certificate, api-key

Java 11, Spring Boot 2.1.3, Spring 5.1.5

I have a Spring Boot project in which certain endpoints are guarded by an API key. This works just fine at the moment with this code:

```
@Component("securityConfig")
@ConfigurationProperties("project.security")
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityJavaConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityJavaConfig.class);
    private static final String API_KEY_HEADER = "x-api-key";

    private String apiKey;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        APIKeyFilter filter = new APIKeyFilter(API_KEY_HEADER);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> {
            String apiKey = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (this.apiKey != null && !this.apiKey.isEmpty() && this.apiKey.equals(apiKey)) {
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            } else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Access Denied.");
            }

        });

        httpSecurity
            .antMatcher("/v1/**")
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilter(filter)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }
}
```

This successfully requires a header containing an API key, but only for endpoints in `/v1/...`

I have a new requirement to require certificate for authentication. I followed these guides to get X.509 authentication set-up in my project:

- [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/x-509-authentication-in-spring-security)
- [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/securing-rest-apis-with-client-certificates)
- [Codecentric](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/08/x-509-client-certificates-with-spring-security/)

I am running into a few problems, however:

1. Cert is ALWAYS required, not just for `/v1/*` endpoints
2. API key filter no longer works

Here's my updated `application.properties` file:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:cert/keyStore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=<redacted>

server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:cert/trustStore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=<redacted>
server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.client-auth=need
```

And my updated `SecurityJavaConfig` class:

```
@Component("securityConfig")
@ConfigurationProperties("project.security")
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1) //Safety first.
public class SecurityJavaConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityJavaConfig.class);
    private static final String API_KEY_HEADER = "x-api-key";

    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/ping")
    );

    private String apiKey;

    @Value("#{'${project.security.x509clients}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> x509clients;

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        APIKeyFilter filter = new APIKeyFilter(API_KEY_HEADER);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> {
            String apiKey = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (this.apiKey != null && !this.apiKey.isEmpty() && this.apiKey.equals(apiKey)) {
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            } else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Access Denied.");
            }
        });

        httpSecurity
            .antMatcher("/v1/**")
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilter(filter)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .x509()
            .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
                if (x509clients.contains(username)) {
                    return new User(
                        username,
                        "",
                        AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER")
                    );
                } else {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Access Denied.");
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that there's an issue with the order of my chain in `httpSecurity` methods, but I'm not sure what that is. Also, I tried adding the second `configure()` method ignoring the `PUBLIC_URLS`, but that did not help whatsoever. I also tried changing `server.ssl.client-auth` to `want` but it allows clients to connect to my `/v1/*` APIs with no cert at all.

Example output that should not require a cert:

```
$ curl -k -X GET https://localhost:8443/ping
curl: (35) error:1401E412:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:sslv3 alert bad certificate
```

Example output that should require a cert AND an api-key:

```
$ curl -k -X GET https://localhost:8443/v1/clients
curl: (35) error:1401E412:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:sslv3 alert bad certificate
$ curl -k -X GET https://localhost:8443/v1/clients --cert mycert.crt --key mypk.pem 
[{"clientId":1,"clientName":"Sample Client"}]
```

Comment: to support both authentications, you need to create your own authentication provider and handle it yourself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your requirement, as there is no ROLES(Different client's having deifferent access level) **UserDetailService is not required**.
**APIKeyFilter is enough** to work with X509 and API key.

Consider `APIKeyFilter` extends `X509AuthenticationFilter`, If there is a request without valid certificate then filter chain will be broken and error response of `403`/`Forbidden` will be sent.
If certificate is valid then filter chain continues and authentication will be carried out. While validating what we have is only two methods from authentication object 
`getPrincipal()`  - `header:"x-api-key"`
`getCredential()` - `certificate subject`. Where subject is (EMAIL=, CN=, OU=, O=, L=, ST=, C=)
(APIKeyFilter should be configured to return principal and credential object)
 
You can use principal(Your API key) for validating api key sent by client. and
You can use credentials(certificate subject) as a enhancement to identify each client seperately and if required you can grant different authorities for different client.

Recalling your requirement
1. API V1     - Accessed only if Certificate and API key valid.
2. Other APIs - No restrictions

To achieve the above said requirement, necessary codes given below

```java
public class APIKeyFilter extends X509AuthenticationFilter
{
    private String principalRequestHeader;

    public APIKeyFilter(String principalRequestHeader) 
    {
        this.principalRequestHeader = principalRequestHeader;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        return request.getHeader(principalRequestHeader);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

        if(certs.length > 0)
        {
            return certs[0].getSubjectDN();
        }

        return super.getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(request);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String API_KEY_HEADER = "x-api-key";

    private String apiKey = "SomeKey1234567890";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception 
    {
        APIKeyFilter filter = new APIKeyFilter(API_KEY_HEADER);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> {
            if(authentication.getPrincipal() == null) // required if you configure http
            {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Access Denied.");
            }
            String apiKey = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() != null && this.apiKey.equals(apiKey)) 
            {
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Access Denied.");
            }
        });

        http.antMatcher("/v1/**")
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
                .addFilter(filter)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

### Verifying API Response

https   - used for data encryption (ssl certificate sent by server to client)
X509    - used for client identification (ssl certificates generated by using server ssl certificate but different for different clients)
API key - shared secret key for security check.

For verification purpose lets assume you have 3 versions as given below

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController
{
    @RequestMapping(path = "/v1/hello")
    public String helloV1()
    {
        return "HELLO Version 1";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/v0.9/hello")
    public String helloV0Dot9()
    {
        return "HELLO Version 0.9";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/v0.8/hello")
    public String helloV0Dot8()
    {
        return "HELLO Version 0.8";
    }
}
```

Below given response in different cases.
**CASE 1.a Version 1 with valid X509 and API key in header**

```
curl -ik --cert pavel.crt --key myPrivateKey.pem -H "x-api-key:SomeKey1234567890" "https://localhost:8443/v1/hello"
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200
HELLO Version 1
```

---

**CASE 1.b Version 1 with X509 only(No API Key)**

```
curl -ik --cert pavel.crt --key myPrivateKey.pem "https://localhost:8443/v1/hello"
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 403
{"timestamp":"2019-09-13T11:53:29.269+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/v1/hello"}
```

---

***Note:***
In your case, there are two types of certificate
i. Client Certificate with X509
ii: If client not including certificate then for data exchange certificate used in server will be used i.e, certificate without X509

**2. Version X without X509 and without API key in header.**

```
curl "https://localhost:8443/v0.9/hello"
```

If server certificate is self signed certificate(Certificate is invalid without CA  i.e, Certification Authority)

```
curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

---

If server SSL certificate is valid(CA certified) then

**<sub>`curl "https://localhost:8443/v0.9/hello"`</sub>**

> <sub>HELLO Version 0.9</sub>

**<sub>`curl "https://localhost:8443/v0.8/hello"`</sub>**

> <sub>HELLO Version 0.8</sub>

<sub>**Note: Testing Hack if you don't have CA certified SSL certificate in dev environment**</sub>

> Use the **server certificate(.crt)** and **serverPrivateKey(.pem file)** along with request as given below
>
> ```
> curl -ik --cert server.crt --key serverPrivateKey.pem "https://localhost:8443/v0.9/hello"
> ```

---

This can also be verified in Mozilla(for self signed certificate) and can be verified the same in google chrome(if CA certified SSL)
Screen shot given, During first time access

[image]

After adding certificate sent by server.

[image]

Comment: Praveen, thank you very much for your very detailed post, this gave me exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. In fact trying solution to this taught me a lot. While trying this it was very hard to guess what was going wrong. One thing I liked in your question is presentation and your question itself had solution. I just analysed learnt and posted. Thanks.

Comment: PraveenKumar -  Nice presented solution..  I have similar requirement..
1 - API V1 - Accessed Certificate  is valid or API key valid.
API's can be accessed only if certifcate is valid or If API key is present. So sime request will have Certificate and some request will have API Key. How do we hand;e these cases any idea?